# Unable to create src folder in sbteclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, sbteclipse

I am new to sbt and I am trying to create a new project using sbt eclipse plugin.

I have gone through similar post on SO but it didn't help.

**build.sbt** in project directory

```
name := "myproject"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.9.1" % "test"

EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.Default + EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedClasses
```

**plugins.sbt** global

```
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

I run sbt eclipse from command prompt. It creates the project which I can import in Eclipse but it does not create src folders. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I **think** the latest version of sbteclipse no longer generates all the source folders. It only adds the already existing ones to Eclipse's Build Path.

Comment: https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/wiki/Using-sbteclipse it has createSrc parameter. May be I am wrong

Comment: I can only agree that indeed it has that parameter, but since I updated to the latest version of sbteclipse no folders are generated. So I suspect that `create` means something different from what you (and I) would think it means.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. I am using the 5.0.1 version, i expect that the `sbt eclipse eclipseCreateSrc` to create the default src folder structure, but it is not. I am not sure about what I have missed. Please help me if you have figured out anything on this. Thanks.

Comment: I just killed an hour looking through the source code for the plug-in, and I cannot find a call to `File#mkdir()` anywhere. Which is odd: I can't think of a project I've created in the last few years for which I _didn't_ want these directories created by default.

Answer (score 1):

Use SBT Plugin 3.0.0 in Version 4.0.0 the src folders are not create.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "3.0.0")
```